# Should I include Enumerable in NilClass?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, enums

One of the errors that is pretty common in the rails applications I've worked with are nil class errors. Specifically, I frequently see errors like "NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass".

These are annoying, generally benign, and crowd the code with terrible nil checks all over the place.

Here's an example:

```
[3] pry(main)> def test(enum)
[3] pry(main)*   enum.each { |x| puts x }
[3] pry(main)* end
=> nil
[4] pry(main)> test(nil)
NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
from (pry):2:in `test'
[5] pry(main)>
```

Simple to fix if I just put a return unless enum, or return unless responds_to?(:each). But what if I don't want these checks obfuscating my code?

Well, I thought of an idea and I'd like to know if it's a bad idea.

```
[5] pry(main)> class NilClass
[5] pry(main)*   include Enumerable
[5] pry(main)*
[5] pry(main)*   def each; end
[5] pry(main)* end
=> nil
[6] pry(main)> test(nil)
=> nil
[7] pry(main)>
```

I can't imagine that any libraries rely on NoMethodError on nil to drive logic (and if they do it sounds like a library I shouldn't use). Plus, this gives all kinds of benefits because now the whole gamut of enum methods are available:

```
[12] pry(main)> Enumerable.public_instance_methods(false).each { |method| puts "#{method.to_s.ljust(20)} => #{nil.send(method) {} }" if nil.method(method).parameters.empty? }
to_a                 => []
sort                 => []
sort_by              => []
find_all             => []
select               => []
reject               => []
collect              => []
map                  => []
flat_map             => []
collect_concat       => []
partition            => [[], []]
group_by             => {}
all?                 => true
any?                 => false
one?                 => false
none?                => true
min                  =>
max                  =>
minmax               => [nil, nil]
min_by               =>
max_by               =>
minmax_by            => [nil, nil]
take_while           => []
drop_while           => []
lazy                 => #<Enumerator::Lazy:0x007f84623c9d38>
```

so my question is:

**Should I do this?**

**Edit 1**

I would like to point out that functional languages (and rust) do not normally implement nil classes. My actual intention was to turn Nil into a Empty Set so that operations on nil behave like an empty set.

Comment: This is a terrible idea. If you're invoking Enumerable methods on `nil`, you have *big problems* that you need to fix rather than ignore. You should generally have two broad categories of data: objects and arrays. Objects require `nil`, arrays (enumerables) require **empty** checks, if anything. They should **never** be `nil`, they should simply be arrays of 0 items that you can safely iterate over.

Comment: I think something to consider is the fact that many functional languages have no "null" values because they are error prone. This makes nulls into what are effectively "empty sets" and empty set operations are and possibly should be, no-ops.

Answer (score 6):

> Specifically, I frequently see errors like "NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass".
>
> [...]
>
> Simple to fix if I just put a return unless enum, or return unless responds_to?(:each).
>
> [...]
>
> Should I do this?

Absolutely not. If that error is happening frequently, then it means your code is poorly tested and poorly developed.

Having frequent `NoMethodError` it means you failed to properly deal with the data you receive in input and should be considered **a bug you need to fix, not to silence**.

The solution is to start to isolate each piece of code that crashes. Write a test that reproduces the error and deal with the input accordingly. If you expect a value and a nil is passed instead, then you need to understand why there is a nil there, fix your code and make sure to use the tests to avoid regressions.

Comment: I think this only matters if "null" is actually exceptional or if it mostly refers to the value being an empty set. Sometimes when I write a method that returns other enumerables, I return empty sets to allow other code to operate without a null check. Most of the time, I just accept a block and try not to return a value at all. The block either gets called or it doesn't.

Comment: If a method accepts a `nil`, it should deal with it and not raise a `NoMethodError`.

Answer (score 2):

There are more subtle ways of dealing with the issue you are describing.

For methods that you have control over, you can ensure you have a return value set:

```
def should_return_array
  # some code
  arr || []
end

def should_return_hash
  # some code
  options || {}
end
```

When using methods that may return an `Enumerable` or `nil` you can use the same sort of construct:

```
opts = may_return_hash_or_nil || {}
opts.each {|k, v|  }

arr = may_return_array_or_nil || []
arr.each {|v| }

opts = may_return_hash_or_nil
(opts || {}).each {|k, v|  }

arr = may_return_array_or_nil
(arr || []).each {|v| }
```

Comment: Nice! I tend to also use `value.to_a` to do the same thing since `nil.to_a == []`

Comment: @Kevin, that's handy! Didn't know that one